Is there any potential problem when default is written before case?
I saw an odd code snippet(seen below). ):
Is there any potential problem with this code snippet when using C++11 and perior to C++11? The aforementioned code snippet really compiles and works well with gcc.
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    switch (1) {
        default:
            std::cout << "in default" << std::endl;
            break;
        case (1):
            std::cout << "in case 1" << std::endl;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}



What's "odd" about this? This is perfectly normal and valid C++. What makes you think that case labels have to appear in any particular order?

@KerrekSB This is the first time I have seen default is written before case.

It's a bit unusual to have the default case first imo, but it's perfectly valid and semantically the same as if it were last (if there is no fallthrough).

OK, sure, first time for everything, but that doesn't make it odd :-) (Have you seen std::moneypunct_byname before?)

Some people find it quite helpful to put the default case first so that it's easier to spot. Depending on what the switch is doing, there may be good readability reasons for that, too, e.g. if the default is common and the non-default cases are exceptional.

@KerrekSB std::moneypunct_byname supported by std? What a surprise!

@KerrekSB if the cases are exceptional, you wouldn't use a switch, but a regular if. atleast thats how I would write it.

Funny enough, even if we assume that a compiler might just translate it into a big sequence of if statements (at least in the non-optimizing case) which would give a slight performance benefit to cases higher up -- the default will always be last in the chain, regardless of where you put it in the statement since the compiler will always have to check for the other cases first.

The order of case labels only matters, iff any of them is supposed to fall through (i.e. miss the break statements). Other than that, its just a coding style for readability matter. Personally, I find default-first more readable for most case.

Case labels can appear in any order. Pick an order that makes your code easiest to understand. E.g. if your default case is a fatal error (e.g. because you want to catch missing cases at runtime), it might also be nice to put this at the top to declare the switch to be "intended exhaustive".
The semantics of switch are that you jump to the relevant case, so you can use that to do whatever you like. If you break at the end of every case, then the case ordering doesn't matter, but if you allow flowing into the next case, then the order can of course matter. It's often considered subtle and unexpected to fall through cases, though there may be times when it's helpful (and the [[fallthrough]] attribute can be used to make it clear in the code that it's intended).
